# python fails to fetch a whole web page

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am working on a scrapy project to scrape some data on http://58.com

I find some divs are missing from the page when using scrapy to scrape it.

I think this may have something to do with request headers, so I copy the user-agent of Firefox to fake one, just to find it fails.

what can be the problem and how can I solve it?

---

I find the problem is that the web page use ajax to load some data, it's these data that i cannot find.

Comment: Does this happen if you retrieve the page by using `urllib2` ? Also, you might try `beautifulsoup` for scraping. Although it could be that that site is reloading content or so.

Comment: I'd start by using a tool like Firebug or wireshark to see how the browser is loading the page.

Comment: @enzo What does mean "divs", please ? Is it for 'DivX format' ?

Comment: by divs i mean some div elements.

Comment: @enzo How do you observe that some divs are missing ? How do you detect the missings ? If scrapy doesn't work for your case, why not using regexes to find yourself what you need, if it is limited to find some specific strings without having to parse the source code, strictly speaking

Comment: @eyquen "scrapy shell http://xxx.com" and then "view(response)", the result is different from what i see in a web browser.
In fact i find the problem lies in that scrapy does not understand javascript and the some html element is loaded by ajax

Answer (score 1):

use the urllib2, try this 
req.add_header('User-Agent', "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)")

I can pass the request

Answer (score 0):

There is a python binding of libcurl named pycurl. I use pycurl to emulate human behaviors to visit a website and it works well. For html parsing, beautifulsoup is the best choice, you can easily get what exactly you want from the html you fetched using pycurl.

Comment: I find the problem is the web page uses ajax to load these info.
does pycurl work?